# How can I prevent Windows 10 from stretching and cropping my folder thumbnails?

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails

I just upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10 and I noticed that all my folder thumbnails are being stretched for display.

[image]

The picture is a montage: the three entities presented are not in the same folder but the first one (the "folder.jpg" image) is inside both "Big Bob" folders. The first folder is the Windows 10 display, the second is the Windows 7 display. I did it this way so you could see them side by side and compare. As you can see, the Win 10 folder thumbnail has been stretched and cropped while the file itself and its own thumbnail remains at the correct ratio and isn't cropped.

As qasdfdsaq mentioned in the comment that he believed the Win10 picture wasn't stretched, I provided the Win7 version for comparison. As you can see, the Win 7 thumbnail has been transformed with a deeper perspective and yet it looks much thicker than the Win 10 version. So I stand by my assumption that the win 10 version is cropped *and* stretched.

I have this weird occurrence on every single folder, whether it contains a "folder.jpg" or it displays previews of image/video/music files that are inside it. I didn't have that on Windows 8.1 (nor on 7).

I tried removing the thumbnail cache and letting it rebuild by cleaning the system drive and by manually removing the thumbnail cache, but it rebuilds the same way (stretched and cropped) with both methods.

Couldn't find anything more on the web, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that neither the size nor the ratio of the original picture has any effect on the result, except that if you use a square picture, it won't be cropped (but it will be stretched vertically).

EDIT2: If someone with Windows 10 can post in the comments if he/she has the same problem or not, that would be a good start for troubleshooting this one. Thanks.

Comment: The picture does not look stretched at all. It *is* cropped, but that is deliberate so it does not have to be stretched.

Comment: If you try it with a square picture (ratio 1:1), you'll see that the picture isn't cropped at all, but that it still fills the entire rectangle (whose ratio before the perspective transform I estimate to be between 3:4 and 7:8, but certainly not 1:1). I understand that the perspective transform participates in giving the illusion of a vertically stretched picture, but it shouldn't be that much. So, yes, the picture _is_ stretched. Also, previous Windows (XP, Vista, 7 and 8/8.1) didn't crop. So why does 10 crop all of a sudden? And more importantly, is there a way to prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for an answer to the very same problem for a while, but apparently there is nothing we can do about it. According to a Microsoft Support Engineer, "the icons that display are by design and we cannot make any changes to it."

[**Source**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-folder-icons/b14e7e40-564b-4514-a6aa-8a21d64d32ec)

> **EKEeshwar Kumar replied on January 23, 2016**
>
> **Microsoft Support Engineer**
>
> Hi,
>
> Thank you for posting your reply.
>
> I would like to inform that the
>   design is done by the developers and it is not a bug for Windows. If
>   you face any issues regarding the same, feel free to write to us,
>   we'll be glad to assist you.
>
> Regards

Comment: You should quote the relevant information inside your answer, so having to visit a third-party website, isn't required.  This also will allow the link to stop working but the relevant information would be here and not lost.

Comment: Thank you Philippe, first for inquiring about this to Microsoft and also for posting here to let me know about it. It's a shame there isn't a registry hack to change this behavior. I've tried to up the score of your answer but my current rep doesn't allow me to do it yet. I've accepted the answer though ;-)